# Get non zero ids count without where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I wont to get non zero funnel_id count. i get funnel_id count but is also show count of funnel_id is zero and here we do not add where clause here i also get page_count in this query.

```
SELECT `smart_projects`.project_id, `smart_projects`.business_id, `smart_projects`.title,
`page_pages`.`funnel_id` as `funnel_id`, count(distinct(page_pages.page_id) )as page_count, count(distinct(page_pages.funnel_id) )as funnel_count
FROM `smart_projects`
LEFT JOIN `page_pages` ON `smart_projects`.`project_id` = `page_pages`.`project_id`
WHERE  smart_projects.status !=  0
AND `smart_projects`.`business_id` = 'cd9412774edb11e9'
AND `smart_projects`.`created_date` BETWEEN 1558031400 AND 1558722600
GROUP BY `smart_projects`.`project_id`
ORDER BY `funnel_count` ASC
 LIMIT 10
```

page_pages table is :

[image: smart_projects table]

smart_projects table is :

[image]

result is :-

[image]

Expected Result is :

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result? Also, we _really_ don't like images with sample data - it's much easier to read regular ascii text.

Comment: in resul table project_id 346 funnel count should be 0. because funnel_id is 0 page_pages table.

Comment: Please post that expectation in the question, with the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `smart_projects`.project_id, `smart_projects`.business_id, `smart_projects`.title,
 `page_pages`.`funnel_id` as `funnel_id`, count(distinct(page_pages.page_id) )as page_count, count(distinct (CASE WHEN page_pages.funnel_id != 0 then  page_pages.funnel_id ELSE NULL END ) ) as funnel_count
FROM `smart_projects`
LEFT JOIN `page_pages` ON `smart_projects`.`project_id` = `page_pages`.`project_id`
WHERE  smart_projects.status !=  0 
AND `smart_projects`.`business_id` = 'cd9412774edb11e9'
GROUP BY `smart_projects`.`project_id`
ORDER BY `title` DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter out zero values, using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT sp.project_id, sp.business_id, sp.title,
       count(distinct pp.page_id ) as page_count, 
       count(distinct pp.funnel_id ) as funnel_count
FROM `smart_projects` sp LEFT JOIN
      `page_pages` pp
      ON sp.`project_id` = pp.`project_id`
WHERE sp.status <>  0 AND
      sp.`business_id` = 'cd9412774edb11e9' AND
      sp.`created_date` BETWEEN 1558031400 AND 1558722600
GROUP BY sp.`project_id`
HAVING funnel_count > 0
ORDER BY `funnel_count` ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `DISTINCT` is not a function, it is a keyword.  The following expression does not need parentheses.
- `funnel_id` is not appropriate in the `SELECT`, because it is the argument to an aggregation function.

Comment: i add expected result.plz check